# Sort Elastic search result with best _score in Aggregation

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to do an aggregation and then sort the best scored result in top. Even though aggregation is successful, yet its not score sorted. How to make it possible?

```
   "aggs": {
            "group": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "description.keyword",
                    "order": {
                        "description_score": "desc"
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "group_docs": {
                        "top_hits": {
                            "size": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

        }
```

Comment: @Lupanoide Can you share your views?

Comment: As just said, this is not possible because terms aggregation doesn't return any score. It's a kind of groupBy in SQL. It group all values of a certain field, there is no score. You need to change strategy. Please explain better what is your goal. What do you need to be scored? According to which criteria?

Answer (score 0):

As @Lupanoide mentioned scores are not calculated in aggregation so you cannot sort your bucket on document score. Instead [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-collapse.html) can be used

> Allows to collapse search results based on field values. The
>   collapsing is done by selecting only the top sorted document per
>   collapse key

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "collapse": { --> group by on given field
    "field": "sources.keyword"
  }
}
```

By default search results are sorted on "score" so you don't need to add "sort"